# duplicate error in xcode with sharekit on phonegap (but not with phonegap-plugin)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova, sharekit

I have a xcode/phonegap project where I want to use the sharekit - not as phonegap-plugin but from inside the objective-c code, so no need to implement the phonegap plugin version of the sharekit.

I import the sharekit classes and want to compile but there is an error telling me that the reachability class is defined twice: one inside phonegap and one inside sharekit.

> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Reachability.reachabilityRef in
>   /Users/Shared/PhoneGap/Frameworks/PhoneGap.framework/PhoneGap and
>   /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-cjsfgpsrurmznybczdgqiotrctnm/Build/Intermediates/Appname.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppnameID
>   .build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o for architecture i386
>   Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/**iPhoneSimulator**.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1

**Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1**

how could I get rid of this?

thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the Reachabilty Class Group from the Sharekit Group and added

```
#ifdef PHONEGAP_FRAMEWORK
#import <PhoneGap/Reachability.h>
#else
#import "Reachability.h"
#endif
```

to the SHK.m